# Não consigo dar POST com WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Estou estudando WebAPI e usando o Postman para testar. Fazendo alguns testes percebi que não chega nada quando envio o json usando o Postman para o WebAPI. Pesquisei muito sobre POST usando WebAP, mas não sei pq não está dando certo...

Segue o código da Controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using WebApi.Model;

namespace WebApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ClienteController : ApiController
    {
        private IList<Cliente> novosClientes = new List<Cliente>();

        private Cliente[] Clientes = new Cliente[]
        {
            new Cliente { ID = 1, Nome = "Joel Jordison", Email = "tarara@tarara.com.br", Ativo = true },
            new Cliente { ID = 2, Nome = "Bill Gates", Email = "gates@microsoft.com", Ativo = true },
            new Cliente { ID = 3, Nome = "Aleister Crowley", Email = "aleister@therion.com", Ativo = false }
        };

        // GET: api/cliente
        [HttpGet]
        public Cliente[] Get()
        {
            return Clientes;
        }

        // POST api/cliente
        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage Post(Cliente value)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Começo");

            Debug.WriteLine("-------------Value-----------------");
            Debug.WriteLine(value.ID);
            Debug.WriteLine(value.Nome);
            Debug.WriteLine(value.Email);
            Debug.WriteLine(value.Ativo);
            Debug.WriteLine("-------------Fim Value-------------");

            if (value != null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Não nulo");
                novosClientes.Add(value);
                Clientes = novosClientes.ToArray();
                return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }

            Debug.WriteLine("Fim");

            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }
}
```

Estou tentando enviar o json selecionando POST, depois eu Body e colocando o json no Postman assim:

```
{
    "ID": 10, 
    "Nome": "Joana", 
    "Email": "joana@joana.com.br", 
    "Ativo": true 
}
```

Como resposta, recebo isso:

```
{
  "Version": {
    "Major": 1,
    "Minor": 1,
    "Build": -1,
    "Revision": -1,
    "MajorRevision": -1,
    "MinorRevision": -1
  },
  "Content": null,
  "StatusCode": 200,
  "ReasonPhrase": "OK",
  "Headers": [],
  "RequestMessage": null,
  "IsSuccessStatusCode": true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

O *attribute* `Route` não deveria estar ali. Este atributo serve para definir uma rota para **um método**, logo ele não deveria estar sendo aplicado na classe. Além disso, o valor dele está errado, se você quer que sua rota seja **api/controller** não vai precisar do attribute, isso levando em consideração que você tenha as rotas padrões do Web API configuradas no arquivo `WebApiConfig.cs`. Caso você não tenha as rotas padrões configuradas por algum motivo, você deve mudar o *attribute* e seu valor para

```
[RoutePrefix("api/clientes")]
public class ClienteController : ApiController { ... }
```

Obs.: Ao definir um método chamado **`Get`** ele será automaticamente mapeado para verbo HTTP **GET**, logo o *attribute* **`[HttpGet]`** é desnecessário, mas isso não faz diferença, pode mantê-lo ali mesmo.

---

Caso precise, aqui vai a configuração padrão de rotas

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Ainda continuo não conseguindo fazer um POST. Quando tento fazer o POST recebo isto `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:50143/api/Cliente. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405`

Answer (score 0):

Eu não costumo usar o postMan para testes, gosto de criar um html com js, segue um exemplo que eu criei para os meus testes abaixo, para funcionar com o seu exemplo basta trocar a URL e os parâmetros do seu objeto.

Exemplo HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>  
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {

            $.post("http://localhost:51589/api/Usuarios",{Nome:'Adriano',PerfilId:1}, function( data ) {
                alert('Usuário salvo com sucesso!');
            });
        }); 
    </script>
</head>
<body> 
</body>
</html>
```

Exemplo Api

```
 // POST api/USuarios
        [ResponseType(typeof(Usuario))]
        public IHttpActionResult PostUsuario(Usuario usuario)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }    


     return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = usuario.Id }, usuario);
        }
```

Comment: Qual versão vc usa no WebAPI? Desde já agradeço sua ajuda!

Comment: estou usando a 2.0

Comment: No meu exemplo, vc viu alguma coisa errada?

Comment: Tentei o seu exemplo e recebi `Request Method:POST Status Code:200 OK`, mas quando dou dar um GET vejo que não atualizou o array

Comment: você viu no firebug se o retorno do seu get não esta com 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin  ?

Comment: Tentei sim. Não deu em nada.

Answer (score 0):

Já passei por esse tipo de problema e para resolver fiz duas alterações, mas uma delas não é o caso dessa issue.

O trecho da declaração do método POST da forma que está quando você faz uma requisição o sistema não consegue realizar a conversão automática do Json para o objeto Cliente. Você deve deixar explícito qual a estrutura de binding o parâmetro vai utilizar. Nesse caso, como a requisição tem o Json informado no corpo então deve declarar o método da seguinte forma:

`

```
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] Cliente value)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Começo");

        Debug.WriteLine("-------------Value-----------------");
        Debug.WriteLine(value.ID);
        Debug.WriteLine(value.Nome);
        Debug.WriteLine(value.Email);
        Debug.WriteLine(value.Ativo);
        Debug.WriteLine("-------------Fim Value-------------");

        if (value != null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Não nulo");
            novosClientes.Add(value);
            Clientes = novosClientes.ToArray();
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }

        Debug.WriteLine("Fim");

        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
```

`